# speed up function in bash so it will finish scan in 10 times faster

Tags: bash, freebsd

i use below function to scan if in my network port 80 is open or not,

in case if port is closed, it wait for 1sec, how can i seed it up?

so the same function will can run 10 times in the same time or something like?

```
while read ip
do
    nc -zw1 $ip 80 && echo "$ip" >> opened || echo "$ip" >> closed;
done < list
```

or maybe an alternative what will do the same more fast,

Thank you.

Comment: You can run each pipeline in the background, but you might want to look at using [`nmap`](http://nmap.org) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read ip
do
    (nc -zw1 $ip 80 && echo "$ip" >> opened || echo "$ip" >> closed) & # The & will run each test in the background, allowing all tests to be done more or less concurrently.
done < list
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a network scanner like `nmap`:

```
sudo nmap -iL list -Pn -p 80
```

nmap will scan multiple hosts in parallel and can do SYN scans rather than regular connection attempts, making it two orders of magnitude faster.